# Multi-columns Tables

Tags: tables, multicolumn

how can I remove the light gray color in the first column below t. Tq.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
{\textbf{\caption {Numerical results for $y_{1}(t)$, $y_{2}(t)$ (light gray color) in Example \ref{example 1.2}}}}
 \begin{center}
\label{table61} \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{.5cm}}
\begin{footnotesize}
\vspace{0.5cm} \scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
&      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{CWFD} \\
\cline{3-6} \\
t&ChC\;\cite{} &$M=10, k=1$&$M=7, k=2$&$M=10, k=2$&$M=12, k=2$\\\hline
0.2 &0.389$\times10^{-9}$&3.766$\times10^{-10}$&2.366$\times10^{-9}$&2.030$\times10^{-12}$&3.228$\times10^{-15}$\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}    &0.623$\times10^{-6}$&1.005$\times10^{-8}$&1.293$\times10^{-8}$&4.668$\times10^{-11}$&3.822$\times10^{-14}$\\\hline
0.4 &0.535$\times10^{-9}$&2.948$\times10^{-9}$&2.787$\times10^{-9}$&9.351$\times10^{-14}$&4.062$\times10^{-15}$\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}& 0.408$\times10^{-6}$&5.823$\times10^{-8}$&1.425$\times10^{-9}$&4.220$\times10^{-12}$&2.814$\times10^{-14}$\\\hline
0.6 &0.143$\times10^{-7}$&1.801$\times10^{-9}$&4.003$\times10^{-9}$&7.782$\times10^{-12}$&2.632$\times10^{-14}$\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}     & 0.362$\times10^{-6}$&3.758$\times10^{-8}$&6.360$\times10^{-8}$&5.791$\times10^{-11}$&7.850$\times10^{-13}$\\\hline
0.8 &0.501$\times10^{-7}$&1.198$\times10^{-11}$&1.296$\times10^{-8}$&1.868$\times10^{-11}$&4.453$\times10^{-14}$\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}     & 0.475$\times10^{-5}$&6.207$\times10^{-10}$&1.462$\times10^{-7}$&1.226$\times10^{-10}$&1.649$\times10^{-12}$\\\hline
1.0 &0.332$\times10^{-6}$&1.152$\times10^{-10}$&1.730$\times10^{-8}$&2.728$\times10^{-11}$&2.181$\times10^{-14}$\\
 \rowcolor{lightgray}    &0.982$\times10^{-5}$&9.882$\times10^{-10}$&1.985$\times10^{-7}$&1.696$\times10^{-10}$&2.261$\times10^{-12}$
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please re-format your code. Use the bottom "{ } (Code Sample)" to do it again.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (mwe). According to your code, just remove `\rowcolor{lightgray}`. Do you mean only the 1st column?

Comment: Yes I want to have the first column with white color but others gray color

Comment: There are also the `\columncolor` and `\cellcolor` commands.

Answer (score 3):

See, if you like to have something similar to the following:

[image]

In resetting of your table I exploit some packages which make it easy and gives better (more beautiful) results:

- for caption: `caption` package with option `font=\bf`
- for columns type I use `S` from package `siunitx`, which simplify typing of cel content from `&0.389$\times10^{-9}$` to `0.389e-9`

Beside this the mismatch with table font size I replace with simple `\footnotesize` (this is easy change to desired size), replace `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` with `\centering`, which not add spurious vertical space. Also is considered suggestion in above comments how to remove gray colors in the first column with `\cellcolor{white}`.

According to my taste I also remove horizontal lines in table, but if you like to have, you can return it :-). With all thee the MWE with your table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption {Numerical results for $y_{1}(t)$, $y_{2}(t)$ (light gray color) in Example \ref{example 1.2}}
    \centering
\label{table61} 
%\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspac.5cm}}
%\begin{footnotesize}
%\vspac0.5cm}
%    \scriptsize
    \footnotesize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{     S[table-format=1.1]
                *{5}{S[table-number-alignment = center,
                       table-format = 1.3,
                       table-figures-exponent = 2]}
                }%ccccc}
 &      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{CWFD} \\
    \cline{3-6}
t   &   ChC \cite{} 
                & {$M=10, k=1$} 
                           & {$M=7, k=2$} 
                                      & {$M=10, k=2$} 
                                                  & {$M=12, k=2$}   \\
    \hline
0.2 & 0.389e-9 & 3.766e-10 & 2.366e-9 & 2.030e-12 & 3.228e-15       \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\cellcolor{white} 
    & 0.623e-6 & 1.005e-8  & 1.293e-8 & 4.668e-11 & 3.822e-14       \\
0.4 & 0.535e-9 & 2.948e-9  & 2.787e-9 & 9.351e-14 & 4.062e-15       \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\cellcolor{white} 
    & 0.408e-6 & 5.823e-8  & 1.425e-9 & 4.220e-12 & 2.814e-14       \\
0.6 &0.143e-7 & 1.801e-9   & 4.003e-9 & 7.782e-12 & 2.632e-14       \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\cellcolor{white}
    & 0.362e-6 & 3.758e-8  & 6.360e-8 & 5.791e-11 & 7.850e-13       \\
0.8 & 0.501e-7 & 1.198e-11 & 1.296e-8 & 1.868e-11 & 4.453e-14       \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\cellcolor{white}
    & 0.475e-5 & 6.207e-10 & 1.462e-7 & 1.226e-10 & 1.649e-12   \\
\cellcolor{white} 
1.0 & 0.332e-6 & 1.152e-10 & 1.730e-8 & 2.728e-11 & 2.181e-14   \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\cellcolor{white} 
    & 0.982e-5 & 9.882e-10 & 1.985e-7 & 1.696e-10 & 2.261e-12   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{footnotesize}
%\end{center}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending the use of the siunitx package and for simplifying the material inside the tabular environment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you *not* highlight alternating rows in gray. Instead, simply insert a bit of whitespace after every second row, and provide a short legend to inform readers what the first and second row of each pair of rows shows. Incidentally, you needn't use `\footnotesize` or even `\scriptsize` -- the tabular material fits if you use the normal font size. Just use a `tabular*` environment to assure that the table fits inside the text block.

As @Zarko does in his answer, I would also recommend that you use some of the tools of the `siunitx` package to simplify and structure the inputs of the tabular material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}
\captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.75\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Numerical results for $y_{1}(t)$ and $y_{2}(t)$ in Example XYZ}
\label{table61}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
%%\small

Results for $y_{1}(t)$ ($y_{2}(t)$) are shown in upper (lower) row of each pair of rows.

\bigskip
\sisetup{tight-spacing = true, table-format = 1.3, table-figures-exponent = 2}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{5}{S} }
$t$ & {ChC} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{CWFD} \\
\cmidrule{3-6}
&& {$M=10$, $k=1$} & {$M=7$, $k=2$} & {$M=10$, $k=2$} & {$M=12$, $k=2$}\\
\midrule
0.2 &0.389E-9&3.766E-10&2.366E-9&2.030E-12&3.228E-15\\
    &0.623E-6&1.005E-8&1.293E-8&4.668E-11&3.822E-14\\
\addlinespace
0.4 &0.535E-9&2.948E-9&2.787E-9&9.351E-14&4.062E-15\\
    &0.408E-6&5.823E-8&1.425E-9&4.220E-12&2.814E-14\\
\addlinespace
0.6 &0.143E-7&1.801E-9&4.003E-9&7.782E-12&2.632E-14\\
    &0.362E-6&3.758E-8&6.360E-8&5.791E-11&7.850E-13\\
\addlinespace
0.8 &0.501E-7&1.198E-11&1.296E-8&1.868E-11&4.453E-14\\
    &0.475E-5&6.207E-10&1.462E-7&1.226E-10&1.649E-12\\
\addlinespace
1.0 &0.332E-6&1.152E-10&1.730E-8&2.728E-11&2.181E-14\\
    &0.982E-5&9.882E-10&1.985E-7&1.696E-10&2.261E-12\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```